Rename all files in a directory with specific format
I have 100s of files in a directory that are all in the same format like this:
Recon-2024Jun03.xlsx
Recon-2024Jun02.xlsx
Recon-2024Jun01.xlsx
etc...

I need to rename them all with a new format like this:
Recon-240603.xlsx
Recon-240602.xlsx
Recon-240601.xlsx
etc...

I have this piece of code, but I am unsure what to put inside the replace function:
import os
[os.rename(f, f.replace('.', '.')) for f in os.listdir(path)]

here is the date format I need
'%y%m%d'


You must take the date field from each filename and convert it to the new form. Use the date class to parse the original string to a Date object and then convert it to a string in the new format.

What is the list comprehension for? os.rename() doesn't return anything, so you're just making a list full of None. It's not pythonic to use a list comprehension just to perform a loop, use a for statement.

You can use strptime and strftime from the datetime module to convert these to your desired format (note that this answer assumes all of your files follow the format 'Recon-<datestamp>.xlsx')
import datetime as dt
import os


files = [
    'Recon-2024Jun03.xlsx',
    'Recon-2024Jun02.xlsx',
    'Recon-2024Jun01.xlsx',
]

for file in files:
    old_datestamp = dt.datetime.strptime(file, 'Recon-%Y%b%d.xlsx')
    new_datestamp = old_datestamp.strftime('Recon-%y%m%d.xlsx')
    os.rename(file, new_datestamp)

strptime is used to get a datetime object from the input filename, and strftime is used to convert that datetime object to a string in the new format
